# dnscrypt-proxy - find the best DNS resolver and update the dnscrypt-resolvers list

Tags: dns, dnscrypt-proxy

I have installed `dnscrypt-proxy` and the default resolver I have is: `resolver1.dnscrypt.eu`.

- Is it possible to find the fastest DNS resolver from the list [here](https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv):
- Also I have installed the program from [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~anton+/+archive/ubuntu/dnscrypt), so my DNS resolvers list is not the same as in the github master, so is it possible/safe to update my local list in `/usr/share/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv` with the new one from the link above?

Thanks

Comment: that csv list is not available anymore - any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. All things are possible given enough time and effort.

One way to accomplish DNS benchmarking is to utilize the `namebench` program as mentioned [here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62222/how-to-test-dns-speed) It hasn't been updated since 2010 but is available [here](https://code.google.com/archive/p/namebench/downloads?page=1)

Another way to accomplish this on a recent version of Ubuntu  (limited testing accomplished on 14.04.5) is to:

1) [Download](https://www.grc.com/files/DNSBench.exe)  Gibson Research Centers [DNS Benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) (Granted this is also hasn't been updated since 2010)

2)Launch it with Wine with `wine DNSBench.exe` via the terminal in the directory you downloaded it to or right click on it in nautilus and select Open with -> Wine Windows Program Loader.

[image: DNSBench]

To add your custom list of DNS servers, Click the Nameservers tab and then the Add/Remove button.

[image: Add/Remove]

Limitation: If <kbd>Add System`s Nameservers</kbd> doesn't do the trick you'll need to parse your csv file to obtain the IP addresses and add them (manually?) to the DNSBench list of servers.

Then Click <kbd>Benchmark</kbd> to complete the benchmark testing. This can take awhile so it's a good time to get up from the keyboard and stretch.

Once Benchmarking is complete you can click the <kbd>Tabular Data</kbd> button which will provide final bench mark results sorted from fastest to slowest.

Regarding the safety of updating your local list in `/usr/share/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv` You can safely test updating any file on your system provided you have a good strategy. There's nothing quite like having a backup copy to insure that you can revert your changes if something goes awry. One way to accomplish this would be to simply issue the command `sudo cp /usr/share/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv /usr/share/dnscrypt-proxy/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv.bak`